# Can I use high version torch and low version cuda?

Tags: pytorch

I'm setting up my Conda environment with a remote GPU to use Pytorch.
The GPU I use is only `NVIDIA-SMI 396.54`, so I can only use cuda version 9.2

However, I need to use a higher version torch to be able to use some attributes.

I tried

```
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 cudatoolkit=9.2
```

But this results in

```
print(torch.version.cuda)>> None
```

```
torch.cuda.is_available() >> False
```

Comment: have you tried `conda install pytorch` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I would check.

You may have unintentionally installed the pytorch cpu version or had it in your environment first, before running the above command. Even if you install the gpu version of Pytorch, if you already have the cpu version of pytorch then `torch.cuda.is_available()` will return False. Therefore I suggest checking out this link:
[Forum on why Pytorch is CPU version even after installing cudatoolkit version](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/installing-pytorch-with-conda-installs-cpu-only-version/72214/2)

Although, I am pretty sure the above thing is your problem, I suggest looking at this second thing.

For understanding how to download previous version of Pytorch refer to this link. https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

After looking at this, I suggest starting a new conda env and running your conda install command first.

Sarthak Jain